# How do I get rid of the error "self signed certificate in certificate chain" in VS Code when installing plugins?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have installed VS Code (Windows 7 x64) and when I try to install any plugin I get the error "self signed certificate in certificate chain".
I set `"http.proxyStrictSSL": false` and it helped me to get list of plugins but when i push the install button I get the error.

I have not set the proxy settings on my computer but I know that the network in my office is protected by CheckPoint firewall.

Can I somehow solve this problem to install plugins in VS Code?
Or if I need to ask our security service for some extra permitions what kind of permit is required?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older post, but I ran into the same problem... maybe this will help someone.  I got it to work by using the setting you mentioned, as well as running as Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Install the [win-ca](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ukoloff.win-ca) extension before installing the desired extension.

## Details

In my case, on Windows, I was trying to install the [Partial Diff](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryu1kn.partial-diff) extension:

```
PS C:\> code-insiders.cmd --install-extension ryu1kn.partial-diff
```

But I was getting this error:

```
Installing extensions...
self signed certificate in certificate chain
Failed Installing Extensions: ryu1kn.partial-diff
```

Following the [advice in a discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-github-issues-prs/issues/28#issuecomment-397826204), I installed the [win-ca](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ukoloff.win-ca) extension first:

```
PS C:\> code-insiders.cmd --install-extension ukoloff.win-ca
Installing extensions...
Installing extension 'ukoloff.win-ca' v3.1.0...
(node:118392) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(node:118392) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
Extension 'ukoloff.win-ca' v3.1.0 was successfully installed.
```

And then I was able to successfully install the Partial Diff extension:

```
PS C:\> code-insiders.cmd --install-extension ryu1kn.partial-diff
Installing extensions...
Installing extension 'ryu1kn.partial-diff' v1.4.0...
(node:113096) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(node:113096) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
Extension 'ryu1kn.partial-diff' v1.4.0 was successfully installed.
```